# Google Earth Plugin, show form in Panel

Tags: extjs, google-earth-plugin

I am using the Google Earth Plugin with Extjs 4. Although I think I am missing something small.

I have my Google Earth Plugin with a lot of created Placemarks.

The control panel looks like this.

```
// Create control panel
var controlPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Control Panel',
    width: 280,
    height: this.height,
    border: true,
    collapsible: false,
    renderTo: 'westPanel',
    layout: 'accordion',
    layoutConfig: {
        animate: true
    },
    defaultType: 'panel',
    defaults: {
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px'
    }
});
```

Create a folder.

```
var folder = this.earth.createFolder("PLaceMark Name");

placemark = this.earth.createPlacemark('');

var point = this.earth.createPoint('');

point.setLatitude(my_lat);      
point.setLongitude(my_long);
placemark.setGeometry(point);

folder.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
```

In the end I make the folder visible.

```
this.earth.getFeatures().appendChild(folder);
folder.setVisibility(true);

// Add panels
controlPanel.add(earthPanel.getLayersPanel());
controlPanel.add(earthPanel.getOptionsPanel());
controlPanel.add(earthPanel.getFoldersPanel());
controlPanel.doLayout();
```

What I do get to see all the placemarks on the map but on the Panel there is no option to make that folder visible / hidden.

All I want to do is create an option on the panel where I can hide my placemarks or show them with a check-box.

Maybe there is a way to build a custom panel with check-boxes and execute JavaScript when I check / unchecked the box.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using ExtJs > 4 you don't need to call `doLayout()`. ExtJs has a checkbox component so you can create whatever you want ;)

Comment: Of course yes. 
Thanks for the hint, I know exactly what I need to do now. :D

Comment: If you have more questions regarding this topic ask us!